# Insert Custom LinearLayout in ListView Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

i know this question is still answered in many posts. and theoretically i know the answer, but in this case i can't get it work.

I have a custom BaseAdapter

```
@Override
public Row getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ...

    Row view = (Row) convertView;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = (JVxDataRow) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_base, null);;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
    return view;
}
```

this works fine, the row_base.xml is inflated correct, and my list view gets all entries.
the row_base.xml consist only of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mh.android.ui.Row
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/datarow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp" />
```

therefore i want to remove that file and instead instantiate this programmatically.
my code for that - which doesn't work - is as following:

```
@Override
public Row getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ...

    Row view = (Row) convertView;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = new Row(context);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
    return view;
}
```

to get it work i have to put some layoutparameters in the Row's constructor and moved the inflate from onFinishInflate to the constructor:

```
public Row(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    this.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datarow3, this, true);

    this.addView(container);
}
```

the datarow3.xml looks:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/table_row_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<mh.android.ui.DataItem
    android:id="@+id/dataitem_slot1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" >
</mh.android.ui.DataItem>
<mh.android.ui.DataItem
    android:id="@+id/dataitem_slot2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" >
</mh.android.ui.DataItem>
</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is in the BaseAdapter when i change from inflating the xml to instantiate programmatically, the listview is inside a LinearLayout.

Now the exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13203): java.lang.ClassCastException:     android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1170)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1252)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
E/AndroidRuntime(13203):    at
```

what's going wrong there?
thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are all comments are gone?
The solution for my problem:

```
container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datarow3, this, true);
this.addView(container);
```

changed to

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.datarow3, this, true);
```

the layout do not need to be added after inflate it.